# Count and sum unique Values POwer BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to get the sum of Sales with uniuqe Catatery i'm using DAX Formula below

```
Countoracle = CALCULATE(SUM('Data Source'[Sales) ,DISTINCTCOUNT ('Data Source'[ItemAr]))
```

getting error

> The True/False expression does not specify a column. Each True/False expressions used as a table filter expression must refer to exactly one column.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at it the wrong way.
Rather than cramming it into one measure try breaking them into 2 parts.
And please elaborate your question. What is your goal here ?

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I know but when click on comment it says " You must have 50 reputation to comment."